# How to update an array of objects in firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Have a json structure as follows. How can an element/the marks section be updated?

Have tried using arrayUnion approach, by passing a list/hashmap of Mark object. But did not work.

saw an example https://medium.com/@thilanka.nuwan89/cloud-firestore-updating-object-arrays-be6ded13e76f

but could not figure out a way to achieve this in Java.

```
student {
 "id" : "1122",
 "marks" [{
   "physics" : "95",
   "maths" : "98"
 }]
}
```

To be able to update the marks section completely/partially.

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: passing the above json as such to firestore.

Comment: If you want to get helped, please add the screenshot I have asked you.

Comment: only have access through APIs. yet to get the console access

Comment: There is no syntax for updating an array by index.   You have to read the document, make change to the array in memory, then udpate the document with the new data.

Comment: db.collection(TARGET_COLLECTION).doc(newLocation.hostId).update({
          locations: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove({
            id: locationId,
            name: oldLocation.name,
            description: oldLocation.description
          })
        })
As mentioned in the link, how is the above logic implemented in Java? { id: locationId, name : location.name }. Have tried List<Entity>, Map<Entity>.

Comment: The question is not about updating an array by index. It is about updating an array of objects. Please do not close this question.